# Redirect the URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have developed a module in codeigniter and the URL is as :

```
http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/click

http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/view

http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/pass_thru
```

I also have some legacy application developed in asp and there are number of URL which I need to redirect to my new module now so I want the below 3 links should be redirected to my new module developed in CI.

```
http://localhost/track/click_thru.asp

http://localhost/track/view_tracker.asp

http://localhost/track/pass_thru.asp
```

Is this possible in Codeigniter or I should do it in .htaccess?

Comment: may be it can be possible in CI in routing, or else Htaccess.

Comment: Try redirect('http://example.com');

Comment: @paritosh, that's not gonna work, because the 2 project save in 2 different folder, the redirect working only on the same project folder

Comment: @CodeSlayer thank you for the update I read its documentation

Comment: Simply used htaccess redirect /track/click_thru.asp http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/click/
redirect /track/view_tracker.asp http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/view/
redirect /track/pass_thru.asp http://localhost/bwn/index.php/track/track/pass_thru/

Answer (score 0):

Raw PHP

```
header("Location: http://google.com, TRUE, 302");
```

CI

```
$this->output->set_header("Location: http://google.com, TRUE, 302");
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP and PHP are completely separate. Therefore your codeigniter application is not going to be able to redirect .asp files to .php

### Codeigniter -> codeigniter

Within Codeigniter you can re-route URLs in the **routes.php** file.

e.g in **routes.php**

```
$route['hello'] = "goodbye";
```

would re-route `/hello` to the `goodbye` controller. This is re-routing, not re-directing.

### Codeigniter -> asp

You can redirect controllers to specific URLs. (ie Codeigniter -> ASP). This is a 301 redirect.

e.g in your controller have

```
redirect('/track/pass_thru.asp', 'location', 301);
```

However codeigniter can't redirect your asp files to codeigniter.

### Asp -> codeigniter

**1) In your raw .asp files you can create redirects**

e.g
**/track/pass_thru.asp**:

```
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","/bwn/index.php/track/track/pass_thru"
%>
```

**2) Or you can have these redirects done through .htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /track/pass_thru.asp /bwn/index.php/track/track/pass_thru
```

Answer (score 0):

in route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'errors';
```

and in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

these changes and setting of base_url solved this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to changes on routes.php or .htaccess file we can redirect any where using redirect method you just need to provide full path.

```
    redirect('http://localhost/track/click_thru.asp');
```